# Visual studio 2015 update 3 and sql server 2016 "the visual studio CRC package did not load correctly"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016

I just downloaded Visual studio 2015 update 3. When I open up sql server I get this error message followed by a shutdown of sql server.

`Visual studio 2015 update 3 and sql server 2016`

The activitylog.xml

```
`  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>295</record>
    <time>2016/07/29 21:31:52.667</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{6B238C39-B163-467E-83DB-A2DEC10459ED}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>296</record>
    <time>2016/07/29 21:31:52.667</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Appid denied the loading of package</description>
    <guid>{6B238C39-B163-467E-83DB-A2DEC10459ED}</guid>
  </entry>
</activity>
`
```

I tried deleting the following directory and restarting vs but nothing worked
C:\Users{your_username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

I also tried repairing vs and reinstalling it from scratch back to update 2 but nothing is working. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same error after installing Visual studio 2015 update 3.

I went to microsoft . com page titled "Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)" and installed the "Download SQL Server Management Studio July 2016 Hotfix update"

here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

After that everything seems to be working normally with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. After I start the SSMS Tool with admin privileges there is no error. :)